# ContentFlow: avoid image-overlapping

Tags: javascript

I'm using ContentFlow (http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/index.php) and I would like to avoid image-overlapping adding 20px more on both left and right sides.
Could you tell me how to implement it?
Many thanks!
Corrado.

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution on this? Am buffled with this problem too! Petros

Answer (score 5):

So, what you do:

1. Install the DEFAULT addon
2. Go to `ContentFlowAddOn_DEFAULT.js` and search for this:

```
    alcCoordinates: function (item) {
                var rP = item.relativePosition;
                //var rPN = item.relativePositionNormed;
                var vI = this.conf.visibleItems; 

                var f = 1 - 1/Math.exp( Math.abs(rP)*0.75);
                var x =  item.side * vI/(vI+1)* f; 
                var y = 1;

                return {x: x, y: y};
            },
```

You are particularly interested in `0.75` number at the end of `var f`.

- change it `1.75` and higher depending opn your preferences.

Comment: I tried it, and the space gain is modest. After a certain treshold, all it does is make the animation odd. Are there other ways to change the distance between items?

Comment: I have discovered that the line `var x =  item.side * vI/(vI+1)* f;` works as a much more direct way to increase the distance between the items. You just multiply it. For example, `var x =  item.side * vI/(vI+1)* f*2.75;`